# ID NOT IN sql not working with Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Below is my SQL statement to get all Wordpress posts that aren't of those IDs.

```
        SELECT *
        FROM wp_posts as p
        WHERE post_type = 'post'
        AND post_status = 'publish'
        AND post_author = 2
        AND ID NOT IN ( 278,268 )
        ORDER BY post_date DESC
        LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2
```

I'm loading posts via ajax from user submissions and I don't want duplicate posts to load so I thought I would limit that by storing the post ids in a session and checking again them when the sql is called again.

This won't get the proper response. If I remove any of the other ANDs then it will work but as it sits right now, it doesn't work. What the heck is wrong with it? There are no errors that come back

Comment: No errors come back because the query succeeds. Other than that, without knowing the table layout and some sample data (perhaps a SQLFiddle) it would be hard for us to speculate.

Comment: an empty result is NOT an error. it's a valid result that happens to contain no rows. since you get no rows, then your filtering logic is invalid (but not 'incorrect').

Comment: Are you sure the code doesn't have string delimiters:  AND ID NOT IN ( '278,268' )?

Comment: Any particular reason to query the database directly instead of using good old [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)?

Comment: We aren't using WP_Query because we are going to be calculating some relevancy within the query as well eventually -  we just wanted to have full control over the query as it's going to grow

Answer (score 0):

I opted just for removing the offset from the query since it won't be grabbing any of the previously loaded posts anyways. Works fine now. I appreciate the responses!